# InstanceAlreadyExistsException how to unload/destroy instance

Tags: java, classloader

Java Spring

There is situation where I want to check if an instance already exists. Then, I want to unload/destroy the instance.

Is there any way I can destroy the existing object? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about JMX, you can unregister the object but not force the destruction of the object.

If you have your MBeanServer and ObjectName you can call

```
if (server.isRegistered(name)) {
  server.unregisterMBean(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize it with new object

```
if(obj != null)
   obj = new objcalass();
```